# What is the term for two file formats that describe the same amount of information?

Tags: data-structures, terminology, information-theory, filesystems

I am working on file formats conversion. Some of them can be converted back and forth to others without losing any information (fields or precision of the numbers encoded), others file format do not take into account some data or meta-data or use approximated values. 
I was looking for a term to describe the first case, where two formats describe the same amount of information. I'm aware of the term isomorph that seems to describe the case quite well but I couldn't find any reference to any isomorph file format. Is there any other term used for describing the case?

Comment: What makes you think there is such a name?  There are many more concepts than there are names.  That's the beauty of language; we can describe interesting concepts that we don't have a single-word name for, and we're not limited to only those things that we already have a word for.

Comment: @D.W. I am not assuming that it exists am just looking for it!

Answer (score 3):

I think that many programmers would look at it in terms of the *conversions* between the two formats, and say that each format can be converted to the other *losslessly*, and that it's possible to make a *round-trip* without losing any data. It's not a standard usage, but if you said that the two formats were *round-trippable* wrt each other, you would probably be understood. That said, you should still explain what that means!

Answer (score 0):

Isomorphic file formats implies semantically that the formats have analogous data structures but no necessarily the same fidelity.

Perhaps this what you want to say: two file formats that have the same (data) fidelity.